# Repeat word in python unlimited times

Tags: python, repeat

for example i want this word to repeat unlimited times
keep repeating

then how it should be?

```
import time
time.sleep(0.6)
print(" Hello World")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an infinite loop

```
while(1):
    print "Hello world"
```

This will run forever

Comment: thanks yours one also  works . but can you tell me how can i make the font size bigger? when it is running inside of the cmd the font is very small

Comment: You can increase the font of which ever terminal you're using. I'm assuming you're in windows. For windows, right click the cmd window and click properties. There should be a font tab where you can adjust the font

Answer (score 0):

for python 3

```
while True:
    print("Hello World")
```

Comment: thanks it works . but can you tell me how can i make the font size bigger?